# display featurecardPanel on google map marker click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

There is a google map with some markers:
http://gulfnews.com/culture/map-of-museums-in-the-uae-1.133398

As you can see, on marker click it displays left featurecardPanel with some data (name, description)

Please advice how can implement this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you trying to do this exactly the way it's being implemented on this site? If so, it's using the google maps embedded API and creating your own custom map. If you want to do this via the javascript API, you'll have to create your own div that slides over.

Comment: @TahTatsumoto I want do this by javascript API but i don't know how can create div on the map.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot you'll have to do, but basically you'll put the map in a wrapper div that contains both the map div and the div that's going to show the content you want. Add a listener to the marker that's going to show/hide the content div.

```
var map;
var overlayShown = false;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.808678, -117.918921),
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.803333, -117.915278),
  map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById("map-overlay");
    if (!overlayShown) {
    overlay.setAttribute("class", "map-overlay-show");
    overlay.innerHTML = "Put some content here.";
    overlayShown = true;
  } else {
        overlay.className = "";
    overlay.innerHTML = "";
    overlayShown = false;
  }
});
```

Here's a rough [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aka15b5x/8/)

Comment: Hi, Im using this technique. Could you tell me how to add multiple markers?

Comment: Without more details I'm not entirely sure what you want. Basically, you'd wrap everything from `var marker` to the bottom in a loop. If you want to create a new question with more details and pm a link, I can help out more.